# Android 10 Vivo funtouch Os killed my foreground service on swipe?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on app in which i start count for long period of time , for this i have startforeground service the service is working fine in all devices except few devices like android 10 vivo funtouch Os. in which when you swipe notification it kills foregorund service , so to resolve this issue  , only few devices behaving like that thanks

```
   class MyCountdownService : Service(){


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

  

    Log.i("Boot","intent is ${intent?.action}")

    showNotification()

    wakeLock =
        (getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).run {
            newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "EndlessService::lock").apply {
                acquire()
            }
        }

    println("intent ${intent }")
    isServiceStarted =true

  if(intent!=null) {
      val action = intent?.action


      when(action){

          MyCountdownService.ADD_SERVICE ->{
              val countdown = intent.getParcelableExtra<CountDown>(Add_kEY)
              schedule(countdown !!)

          }

          else ->{

              Log.i("Boot","Service boot ")
              serviceScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                  smsScheduler.reSchedule()
              }

          }


      }



  }else{





      serviceScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
          smsScheduler.reSchedule()
      }


  }

    return START_STICKY } }
```

//Manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
   
    <service android:name=".service.MyService"

        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow the Steps to enable foreground service in Android 10 Vivo funtouch Os Device.

Settings < Battery < Background Power Consumption Management < Your Application < Select Don't restrict background power usage.
[More details](https://dontkillmyapp.com/vivo)